# How to read from a Storage bucket from a GCE VM with no External IP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, gsutil, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to read a file in a Storage bucket from within a GCE VM using a `gsutil cp` command. The GCE VM uses a custom storage account which has required IAM permissions and access policies to the file within the storage bucket. My observation is as follows:

1. When the VM has an ephemeral external IP associated with it, the `gsutil cp` command works fine and the file is copied successfully.
2. However if there is no external IP assigned the `gsutil cp` command does not work.

In case 2, the `gsutil cp` command produces the following output:

```
gsutil cp gs://<mybucket-name>/<myfile> .
INFO 0304 13:02:18.377339 retry_util.py] Retrying request, attempt #1...
INFO 0304 13:03:20.684459 retry_util.py] Retrying request, attempt #2...
INFO 0304 13:04:25.247341 retry_util.py] Retrying request, attempt #3...
INFO 0304 13:05:34.869920 retry_util.py] Retrying request, attempt #4...
INFO 0304 13:06:52.144510 retry_util.py] Retrying request, attempt #5...
```

Can anyone suggest what to make out of this and whether this is expected behaviour? What is the correct way to read content within a storage bucket from within a GCE VM that has no external IP assigned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is missing for your VM instance without an external IP address, so that it can access Cloud Storage is to enable **Google Private Access** for the subnet of your VM instance.

As stated in the documentation for [Private Access Options for Services](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options):

> VM instances that only have internal IP addresses (no external IP addresses) can use Private Google Access. They can reach the external IP addresses of Google APIs and services.
>
> You enable Private Google Access on a subnet by subnet basis; it's a
> setting for subnets in a VPC network. To enable a subnet for Private
> Google Access and to view the requirements, see [Configuring Private Google Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access)

You simply have to:

1. Go to Console -> VPC network
2. Choose the subnet of your VM instance (for example default -> us-central1)
3. Edit and select Private Google access -> On. Then save.

Also make sure that your VM has access to the Cloud Storage API.

Comment: That was quick clear and very detailed. Thank you @TasosZG. Lastly, are there any cost implications to enabling private access from a subnet? How is this feature priced within GCP?

Comment: I'm not sure so don't take my answer for granted but since I couldn't find it documented anywhere my guess would be that there are no higher costs. Check also the [GCP Pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#network).